# Palindrome checker in MIPS/ASSEMBLY

Tags: assembly, mips, palindrome

I'm working on some code for class, it is written in MIPS assembly for PLPTool 5.2. The program should receive a string of characters via the UART, check if this string is a palindrome, and then use a print function to print either “Yes” or “No”. I have been given a template file that I am supposed to fill in.

I have completed my code but can't get it to work. As I step through line by line I see that it never makes the jump to palindrome_check despite the correct inputs being sent via the UART. My code compiles without error. What can I try next?

```
.org 0x10000000

# Initializations
# NOTE: You may add initializations after line 10, but please do not
# remove or change the initializations to $sp, $s0, $s1, or $s2

li $sp, 0x10fffffc  # Starting address of empty stack
li $s0, 0xf0000000  # UART base address
li $s1, array_ptr   # Array head pointer
li $s2, array_ptr   # Array tail pointer



####################################################################
# Do not make changes to the jump to main, the allocation of
# memory for the array, or the main loop
####################################################################
j main
nop

array_ptr:          # Label pointing to 100 word array
    .space 100

main:
    jal poll_UART
    nop
    jal period_check
    nop
    jal space_check
    nop
    jal case_check
    nop
    jal array_push
    nop
    j main
    nop
####################################################################
# ******************************************************************
####################################################################


# The "poll_UART" function should poll the status register of the UART.
# If the 2^1 bit position (ready bit) is set to 1 then it
# should copy the receive buffer's value into $v0 and send
# a clear status command (2^1) to the command register before
# returning (a return statement is already included). In order to
# receive full credit, $s0 must contain the base address of the UART
# and must be used with the appropriate offsets to access UART
# registers and buffers

poll_UART:

        lw $t0, 4($s0)
    li $t1, 0b10
    and $t2, $t0, $t1
    beq $t2, $zero, poll_UART
    nop
    
    lw $v0, 8($s0)
    sw $t1, 0($s0)
    jr $ra
    nop

# The "period_check" function should check if the current character ($v0)
# is a period ("."). If it is a period then the function should go to the
# label, "palindrome_check". If the character is not a period then it
# should make a nested function call to palindrome_check

period_check:


    li $t3, 0x2E
    beq $v0, $t3, palindrome_check
    nop
    jr $ra 
    nop

# The "space_check" function should check if the current character ($v0)
# is a space (" "). If it is then it should jump to "main" so
# that it skips saving the space character. If not it should
# use the included return.

space_check:


    li $t4, 0x20
    beq $t4, $v0, main
    nop
        jr $ra
    nop

# The "case_check" function should perform a single inequality check.
# If the current character ($v0) is greater than the ASCII value of 'Z',
# which indicates the current character is lowercase, then it should convert
# the value of $v0 to the uppercase equivalent and then return. If the
# current character ($v0) is already uppercase (meaning the inequality
# mentioned before was not true) then the function should return without
# performing a conversion.

case_check:


    li $t5, 0x5A
    slt $t6, $v0, $t5
    li $t7, 1
    beq $t6, $t7, upper_case
    nop
    jr $ra
    nop
          

    upper_case:
    addiu $v0, $v0, -32 
    jr $ra
    nop


# The "array_push" function should save the current character ($v0) to the
# current location of the tail pointer, $s2. Then it should increment the
# tail pointer so that it points to the next element of the array. Last
# it should use the included return statement.

array_push:


    sw $v0, 0($s2)
    addiu $s2, $s2, 4
    jr $ra
    nop

# The "palindrome_check" subroutine should be jumped to by the period
# check function if a period is encountered. This subroutine should contain 
# a loop that traverses the array from the front towards the back (using the
# head pointer, $s1) and from the back towards the front(using the tail
# pointer, $s2). If the string is a palindrome then as the array is traversed
# the characters pointed to should be equal. If the characters are not equal
# then the string is not a palindrome and the print function should be used
# to print "No". If the pointers cross (i.e. the head pointer's address is
# greater than or equal to the tail pointer's address) and the compared
# characters are equal then the string is a palindrome and "Yes" should be
# printed. 
# 
# Remember to restore the head and tail pointers to the first element
# of the array before the subroutine jumps back to main to begin processing the
# next string. Also, keep in mind that because the tail pointer is updated at
# the end of "array_push" it technically points one element past the last
# character in the array. You will need to compensate for this by either
# decrementing the pointer once at the start of the array or using an offset
# from this pointer's address.

palindrome_check:


    addiu $s2, $s2, -4
    scan:
    lw $t8, 0($s1)
    lw $t9, 0($s2)
    bne $t8, $t9, FALSE
    nop

    addiu $s2, $s2, -4
    addiu $s1, $s1 4
    slt $t7, $s2, $s1
    beq $t7, $zero, scan
    nop

    j TRUE
    nop

    TRUE:
    li $a0, 1
    call project3_print
    li $s1, array_ptr
    li $s2, array_ptr
    j main 
    nop

    FALSE:
    li $a0, 0
    call project3_print
    li $s1, array_ptr
    li $s2, array_ptr
    j main
    nop
```

Comment: Where *does* execution go?  Which branch is the first one to not go the way you expect?  It's great that you're single-stepping it in a debugger, but if you want other people to work on it, you should be telling us what you do see as part of your [mcve].  So we don't have to simulate it in our head and guess what input you send on the serial port.

Comment: Its an internal display built in to the compiler tool (PLPTool 5.2). For instance if I input "abba.", When I get to beq $v0, $t3, palindrome_check (in the period check loop) it does not jump to palindrome_check. Is this what you're asking?

Comment: Rather that jumping to palindrome_check as it should, it just cycles on to the code below, following the next jump instruction to "case_check."

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm asking.  What values are in `$v0` and `$t3` at that point?  Apparently not ASCII `'.'`, or the branch would be taken.

Comment: We've seen this awful template here before. "Function calling", non-local gotos,  non standard register usage.  Basically one large `main` that uss `jal` for no good reason.

Comment: @PeterCordes after your question I jumped back on to find the answer and suddenly it was just working. I have no idea what I could have changed. Anyway, my new issue is that my output is inconsistent. The string: abba. ABBA. Abba. abbA. aBBa. AbbA. should produce 6 yes's, but instead I get :   yes, yes, no, no, yes, yes. I get the same result If I input each 'abba" one at a time. The program seems to be picky about when to perform the upper_case conversion.

Comment: Sounds like your upcasing / downcasing isn't working for forcing everything to the same case.  Single-step through that code closely and see where it goes wrong.  Note that your last two mixed-case test cases still only have to match `B` against `B` or whatever, not `b` against `B` or `a` against `a`; both failures are where that happened.

Comment: stepping through the code with the single input Abba. It makes the conversion as it should but it makes the jump to FALSE during the palindrome_check.

Comment: `addiu $s2, $s2, -4 #Decrement the tail pointer (compensate for offset)`    `scan: `                                                                                                                              `lw $t8, 0($s1)       #Load character from the front of the array `                               `lw $t8, 0($s1)  #Load character from the front of the array

Comment: `lw $t9, 0($s2)      # Load character from the back of the array`                               `bne $t8, $t9, FALSE  # If characters don't match, jump to FALSE`

Comment: @PeterCordes it APPEARS to be making the conversions, for instance. abba. makes all the correct jumps.

Comment: What values are in registers?  You're just showing lines of the source; to figure out why a branch was taken when you didn't expect (or vice versa), look at register values.  Normally to read characters you'd use `lb` or `lbu`, but I guess you're pulling them 1 at a time from the UART?  And you're storing each character alone in a 32-bit word for some reason?

Comment: No, you are correct, the conversion isnt happening. The input a. does not get converted, it simply returns without making the jump to upper_case. Whats weirder is that A. will casue the prgram to jump tp upper_case, however a conversion isnt getting made and $v0 remains unchanged.

Comment: I got it sorted. I had an unnecessary step in my case_check that was causing it to bug out. Appreciate your time.